# Why user inputs from consol are not getting read and stored the second time?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Hello good people of StackOverflow community , currently I am facing a problem and I need your advice/help.
I have written a code where it will take user input for Test Cases and for each Test Cases my program will execute and will provide the result.

Also for each Test Cases I am taking some other values from user as well

For ex

`Code`

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int T = sc.nextInt();
    while(T-->0){
    long K = sc.nextLong();
 if (K >= 2 && K <= (10 ^ 12)) {
    int d0 = sc.nextInt();
    int d1 = sc.nextInt();
    //some additional code
    }
}
```

All the variable i.e. `K` , `d0` , `d1` are taking the input for the first time but for the second time `d0` and `d1` aren't taking any values and instead the values are getting stored in variable `K`(for T > 1) and I am not sure why?!

for ex -  The values for `T = 3`

The corresponding values for `K` , `d0` and `d1` when `T = 3` are 5 3 0
`T = 2` are 17 6 7
here the values of `d0` and `d1` are not getting stored instead it is getting stored in `K` only such that `K = 17` and then `K = 6` and end of loop (since T = 0 )

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This code is not able to reproduce the reported issue. Provide a [mre].

Comment: Hi @Tom I think i have got what causing this , it is because of the ```if condition``` i have provided for the range of ```K``` but I am not sure why this is happening. I have also added the code in the original code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`10 ^ 12` is not what you expect it to be.
`^` is the [bitwise-xor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html) operator.

The operator will logically compare each bit of `10` to `12` and will output a `1` at given bit if there is exactly one of the two input bits is 1 (and therefore the other is 0).

`10` in binary is `0b1010`
`12` in binary is `0b1100`
therefore `10` xor `12` is `0b0110` which is `6` in decimal

In order to calculate 10 to the power of 12 use `Math.pow(10,12)`